# How to create animation controller on demand

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-getx

Is it possible to write a function to create an animation controller? I have dynamic data, if my data return 3, I will need to create 3 animation controller.

Edit:
Thank you pskink for the `List.generate` idea. If I wanted to trigger manually using the below function (`List<AnimationController> animationList`)

```
createAnimationController(int sec, String id) {
animationList
    .add(AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: sec))
      ..addListener(() {
        print('hello');
        update([id]);
      }));
return animationList.last; }
```

I notice that my listener does not fire, not sure why.

Comment: `List.create(3, (i) => AnimationController(...))`

Comment: Do you mean generate?

Comment: sure, my fault, of course `List.generate` ;-)

Comment: Thank you for providing the list idea! I have edited my questions which is more accurate to create on-demand but there is a problem, maybe you could help?

Comment: the listener does not fire because you are not calling any `AnimationController.forward` / `reverse` etc methods

Comment: Yes that's the answer! You can answer it and i will mark as correct answer

Comment: ohh, feel free and write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

Working code that return newly generate `AnimationController`:

```
    List<AnimationController> animationList;
    createAnimationController(int sec, String id) {
    animationList
        .add(AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: sec))..forward()
          ..addListener(() {
            update([id]);
          }));
    return animationList.last; 
}
```